# Collection View how to Create TableView Header

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, uicollectionview, header

I would like to Create a **`headerView`** for my `Collection` view.
But it needs to be not a section header. Just I want to see one `headerView` top of my `Collection` view.

I already have a section header for my sections. I don't need that. I research a lot but I didn't find any solution.

I hope somebody helps me. That's headerView needs to be scroll view my `collectionview` as expected.

Comment: You can try some of these solutions - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29655652/how-to-make-both-header-and-footer-in-collection-view-with-swift

Answer (score 0):

You can add a supplementary view to your collectionview and customize it as you like, may [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6bAHxFEZi3o) tutorial help you

Comment: alami thank for your comment. but unfortunelty it shows only and header for section. But I need    without it (section )

Comment: can you provide an image or sketch of what you would like to do?

Comment: I have a Collection view. Which contain many sections League name and events. For example section 0 : Premier League-> Section name inside row  Manchester vs Chelsea . section 1 : Spain League - Real vs barca . I would like to Create banner view top of collectionview as a scrollable. Thats why ı have to implement collectionview header view. But not section header.

Comment: May you can implement what you want by setting a uiview above your collectionview and controlling its height by  implementing didscroll of your collection view.
may this will be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/49931458/11543623

Comment: Thank you for your help. It doesnt help me actually but your support keep me in the box :D. I solved that added another header section. but I used that only for section 0 . Some Collection view protocol methods changed for that. My solution is seems fine hopefully.

Comment: So add your solution as an answer to help others.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227196/discussion-between-ali-alaoi-and-bartu-akman).

Answer (score 0):

Idea is simple, add one section and used that for headerSection seperated by other section readers.

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            if section == 0 {
                return 0
            }

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        
        return viewModel.getNumberOfSection() + 1
     }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        
        if section == 0  {
            return .init(width: view.frame.width, height: 100)

        }

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        
        
        if kind == UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader && indexPath.section == 0 {
            let headerView: headerView  = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier:"headerView", for: indexPath) as! headerView
            return headerView
        }
```